# MYSQL query datatbase with datetime?

Tags: mysql

I have a datetime var:

```
string(19) "2012-09-14 00:00:00"
```

I want to find the 5 rows in the table that are before this datetime.

How could I do this?

```
$db->query("SELECT id, title FROM news WHERE datetime < " . $db->escape($datetime) . ");
```

The above does not appear to work.

Im using mySQL.

Comment: You need to quote the datetime literal string in single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose by quote datetime value and enclose by backtick datetime column name.

```
$db->query("SELECT id, title FROM news WHERE `datetime` < '" . $db->escape($datetime) . "' order by `datetime` desc limit 5");
```